# 'Cannot find the symmetric key 'master key', because it does not exist ' but the key exists--I've used it

Tags: sql-server, encryption-symmetric

This is happening right after we did a migration to a new server and went from 2012 to 2019, so I think it might have something to do with it.
When I ran the below code on my ID on the new server, or on the previous installation of SQL under the user that runs the app(`BlahUser`), it works fine.  However, under the new server it throws a `Cannot find the symmetric key 'master key', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.` error under `BlahUser`.

```
open master key decryption by password = 'Passphrase'


open symmetric key BlahKey
    decryption by certificate BlahCertificate;
```

I have tried running the following on the database in question, in case permissions haven't been migrated properly:

```
GRANT control ON SYMMETRIC KEY::[BlahKey] TO BlahUser; 
GO
grant control on Certificate::BlahCertificate to BlahUser;
go
```

and that has had no effect.   Any ideas?

Adding this edit for extra info:
I took a look at `sys.symmetric_keys` and when I did a select on my Login, vs the app login(BlahUser), I noticed that `sys.symmetric_keys` was present on my login, but not present on the app login.  I ran

`GRANT control ON SYMMETRIC KEY::[##MS_DatabaseMasterKey##] to BlahUser`

but it has had no effect other than showing up in the resultset for sys.symmetric_keys--same error otherwise.

Comment: Adding this for more info:  If I run :
    `ALTER SERVER ROLE [sysadmin] ADD MEMBER [BlahUser]`


 and   `ALTER SERVER ROLE [sysadmin] DROP MEMBER [BlahUser]`
before and after the code in the main body of the message, it works, so this is a perms issue, but I don't know which permission I need specifically.

Comment: I've gotten this to work using `Execute AS` to have the stored proc impersonate the database owner, but that's a bandaid.  Would like a more permanent fix, if possible.

Comment: Is it possible that on the old server the database master key (DMK) was encrypted by the service master key (thereby obviating the need to open it explicitly)? I'd also remove the dynamic SQL for opening the DMK in the interest of providing a minimal viable repro. And, dumb question, you're running the `open master key` statement in the context of the user database in question?

Comment: Yes, it is being opened in the correct DB.  
It is likely that the key was encrypted by the servicemaster key, because I noticed it wasn't opened explicitly in the old server, and I uncommented that code after the migration to the new server.  However, that's only a partial explanation for why it isn't working under the original role.  I don't think I should have to give the user dbo privileges to open the DMK, even temporarily.  I think I'm missing something permissions-related, I just don't know what.

Comment: [The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/open-master-key-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#permissions) says that whomever issues that command needs control permissions on the database. Does BlahUser have that?

Comment: Sadly, it does not.  This is not the answer I was looking for, but I believe it is the correct one.  I had dug around, tried granting permissions on altering keys, etc, but the only permission that seems to work is Control on the db or db_owner.   Lower level of permissions aren't sufficient.

Comment: You can obviate the need to grant that permission by encrypting the DMK with the SMK (i.e. `alter master key add encryption by service master key`). I suspect the reason that permission is needed for the DMK is that it can protect all sorts of stuff in the database.

Comment: That fixed the issue, Thanks.  Also, I found out the `with Execute As` clause in a stored procedure has a side effect that causes the `system_user ` to return neither the actual user the SP runs nor the `Execute As`  user, but some large binary thing instead.  Thanks for the help.